# Make the Textview and button not overlap with each other

Tags: android, eclipse

When I scroll in mobile  my table layout overlaps with text view ,so it becomes invisible because of same font color with the table row background color.During scrolling I want the text view to remain constant and the table and textview does not merge with one another.The '0' at the top is the text view.  Plz help me out developing a small Game.

```
  <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"   
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="top"
    tools:context="com.example.myfirsstpro.MainActivity" >

    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"    
            android:text="0"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

        <ScrollView 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" > 

        <TableLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="20dp"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true" > 
    <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button1"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:layout_width="150dp"
                    android:layout_height="200dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                    android:scaleType="fitXY"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="12"
                    android:textSize="0dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/images_all" />

            <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button2"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:layout_width="150dp"
                    android:layout_height="200dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                    android:scaleType="fitXY"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="9"
                    android:textSize="0dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/images_all" />
            <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button3"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:layout_width="150dp"
                    android:layout_height="200dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                    android:scaleType="fitXY"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="5"
                    android:textSize="0dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/images_all" />
            <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button4"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:layout_width="150dp"
                    android:layout_height="200dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                    android:scaleType="fitXY"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="10"
                    android:textSize="0dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/images_all" />

            </TableRow>

                              <!-- Row Two -->
            <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button5"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:layout_width="150dp"
                    android:layout_height="200dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                    android:scaleType="fitXY"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="5"
                    android:textSize="0dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/images_all" /> 
            <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button6"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:layout_width="150dp"
                    android:layout_height="200dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                    android:scaleType="fitXY"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="8"
                    android:textSize="0dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/images_all" />
            <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button7"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:layout_width="150dp"
                    android:layout_height="200dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                    android:scaleType="fitXY"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="11"
                    android:textSize="0dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/images_all" />
            <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button8"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:layout_width="150dp"
                    android:layout_height="200dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                    android:scaleType="fitXY"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="8"
                    android:textSize="0dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/images_all" />
            </TableRow>
                        <!-- Row 3 -->
            <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/tableRow3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
                 <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button9"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:layout_width="150dp"
                    android:layout_height="200dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                    android:scaleType="fitXY"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="9"
                    android:textSize="0dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/images_all" /> 
            <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button10"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:layout_width="150dp"
                    android:layout_height="200dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                    android:scaleType="fitXY"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="10"
                    android:textSize="0dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/images_all" />
            <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button11"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:layout_width="150dp"
                    android:layout_height="200dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                    android:scaleType="fitXY"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="11"
                    android:textSize="0dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/images_all" />
            <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button12"                
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:layout_width="150dp"
                    android:layout_height="200dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                    android:scaleType="fitXY"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="12"
                    android:textSize="0dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/images_all" />
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/tableRow4"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
            </TableRow>    
        </TableLayout>
        </ScrollView>

    </RelativeLayout>
```

[Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CmZ3q.png) [Image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JUyGH.png) [Image 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XGnNb.png)

Comment: what happens when you scroll ?

Comment: When I scroll table cross the textveiw so the textview gets hidden.The image link which I have uploaded is from my PC Virtual device. I dont have problem with VM I have pblm when I run it in my mobile since the screen size is small I need scrollview but if I scroll the textview goes below the table layout and gets hidden.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"   
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="top"
    tools:context="com.example.myfirsstpro.MainActivity" >

    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"    
            android:text="0"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

        <ScrollView 
        android:layout_below=@"@+id/textView1" <=== added this line
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" > 

        <TableLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="20dp"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true" > 
    <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button1"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:layout_width="150dp"
                    android:layout_height="200dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                    android:scaleType="fitXY"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="12"
                    android:textSize="0dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/images_all" />

            <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button2"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:layout_width="150dp"
                    android:layout_height="200dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                    android:scaleType="fitXY"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="9"
                    android:textSize="0dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/images_all" />
            <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button3"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:layout_width="150dp"
                    android:layout_height="200dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                    android:scaleType="fitXY"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="5"
                    android:textSize="0dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/images_all" />
            <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button4"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:layout_width="150dp"
                    android:layout_height="200dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                    android:scaleType="fitXY"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="10"
                    android:textSize="0dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/images_all" />

            </TableRow>

                              <!-- Row Two -->
            <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button5"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:layout_width="150dp"
                    android:layout_height="200dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                    android:scaleType="fitXY"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="5"
                    android:textSize="0dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/images_all" /> 
            <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button6"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:layout_width="150dp"
                    android:layout_height="200dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                    android:scaleType="fitXY"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="8"
                    android:textSize="0dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/images_all" />
            <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button7"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:layout_width="150dp"
                    android:layout_height="200dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                    android:scaleType="fitXY"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="11"
                    android:textSize="0dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/images_all" />
            <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button8"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:layout_width="150dp"
                    android:layout_height="200dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                    android:scaleType="fitXY"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="8"
                    android:textSize="0dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/images_all" />
            </TableRow>
                        <!-- Row 3 -->
            <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/tableRow3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
                 <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button9"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:layout_width="150dp"
                    android:layout_height="200dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                    android:scaleType="fitXY"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="9"
                    android:textSize="0dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/images_all" /> 
            <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button10"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:layout_width="150dp"
                    android:layout_height="200dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                    android:scaleType="fitXY"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="10"
                    android:textSize="0dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/images_all" />
            <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button11"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:layout_width="150dp"
                    android:layout_height="200dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                    android:scaleType="fitXY"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="11"
                    android:textSize="0dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/images_all" />
            <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button12"                
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:layout_width="150dp"
                    android:layout_height="200dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                    android:scaleType="fitXY"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="12"
                    android:textSize="0dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/images_all" />
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/tableRow4"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
            </TableRow>    
        </TableLayout>
        </ScrollView>

    </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: One more pbm I have in the image link u can see after every column I would have left 5dp margin space. Is there any possibility I can give color to that particular 5dp space.

Comment: <ScrollView 
        android:layout_below=@"@+id/textView1" <=== added this line
        android:background="#ff00ff00"<== will make that space green
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >